# Characters disappear when i type an entry into a string field

Tags: ms-access, text, field

I have a simple table with a field for product codes. It's worked perfectly for years. Today I noticed that when I went to enter the string "BVE" into the product_code field, that access immediately truncated it to "BE".  There are other rows that already contain "BVE" but when i went back to those rows and tried to re-enter BVE access truncated the it to BE when i hit "Enter".

I tried typing it in as lower case "bve" but it too was truncated to "BE". I tried "BBB" and it was not truncated.
I tried copying "BVE" from one of the other rows and when i pasted it into a new row, it too was truncated to "BE".

There are no validation rules or default values set for this "short text" string field.

It's the weirdest thing I've ever seen. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you have autocorrect turned on. You can switch it off under Settings.

Comment: You are correct!!! I went to File > Options > Proofing > Auto Correct Options and deleted the setting that said to replace BVE with BE.  I did not completely turn off AutoCorrect. But I'm considering it.  Thanks for the help.  Seems easy now, but it really had me stumped!!!